# File content manipulation shell scripts replacement

Tags: shell, scripting, bigdata, file-manipulation

We do a lot of complex file content manipulations using shell scripts. Usually these are excel, csv and fixed-length-column files. Some of the operations we do are listed here.

We wanna evaluate alternatives to shell scripts for manipulating these files. A better product or a better tool or a better programming language.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

- Add columns
- Detele columns
- Split columns
- Copy column value to some other rows
- Some columns are dates. Compare the dates in different rows
- Identify the types of the columns. Dates, Numbers, Strings etc.

Comment: You manipulate the content of *Excel* files in shell scripts? Anyway, since you need to work with tabular data, the immediate answer is of course Excel or LibreOffice Calc; after all, that's what those programs are *designed for*. And there is no way to tell numbers from strings from dates in a CSV file, because CSV files don't carry data type information; you may make an informed guess but it remains just a guess.

Comment: Well, we convert an excel into conducive format before manipulating its content. And we wanna manipulate content programmatically, so idk excel, libreoffice might not work.

Comment: Excel has [VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications). Press Alt+F11 to open the VBA integrated development environment. That's what it's for, to manipulate spreadsheets programmatically. (And it is *very very widely* used for this purpose. It is aloso [quite popular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) on this site.) LibreOffice also has a built-in scripting language, but it's probably less well documented.

Comment: thinking If apache nifi would solve my problem.

Comment: Import in a relational database. Compare their import facilities and pricing.